# Is 7th generation intel supports linux?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

Im having a plan of upgrading my system to latest. But with my budget, i can get intel 7th gen pentium.

I am using both ubuntu and windows os now. I know that 7th gen supports windows. But if intel 7th gen not support ubuntu, its a problem right ?

Is any one tried to install ubuntu in 7th gen PCs ???

Thanks,
Praveen Ravipati.

Comment: Which model in 7th Gen??

Comment: intel pentium g4560 kaby lake processor.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? The issue is the largely the kernel, but 4.10 and newer kernels fully support Kaby Lake processors, on previous kernels sometimes special considerations are needed, but they still work in general.

Comment: Why should not work or have problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with 7th gen and Linux, but it's a bug in the processor "HyperThreading" which can also be found in 6th gen processors(*) and also impacts Windows (even if the first ones to diagnose it where Linux developers).

Otherwise, 7th generation processors are supported since kernel 4.5 (and my Ubuntu 16.04 is already on 4.8...)

(*) This said, I have a 6th gen processor which should be suffering from this and my Linux is rather stable (40 days without rebooting an counting).

Comment: Hi! Could you please give some more details regarding this bug?

Comment: Google/DuckDuckGo for "*intel hyper-threading bug skylake kaby lake*"